# Creating resize handles and dashed border for selected element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to build a custom resize function using javascript. What would be the best way to add resize handles and a dashed line around the selected element? Similar to how YUI handles resizing (without using YUI of course), considering the element may already have a border around it that should not be affected.

Would it be absolutely positioning a div over the element to create the dashed border, and 8 smaller divs to create the resize handles?

Comment: I just took a look at the source code for the jCrop plugin and they basically create 4 divs (1 for each border), then 8 other divs for the handles. http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html

Comment: @jessegavin Never seen jCrop before, ill have to give the source code a look myself. I'm liking the moving border. Thanks for the help